# Is it valid to use a generalized model with no replicates

Tags: generalized-linear-model, experiment-design, meta-analysis, poisson-regression

I've got a designed experiment that is a long-term agricultural station. The field is divided into 11 rows and 6 columns (each column has two sub-columns). Each resulting plot represents a unique combination of certain fertilizers and plants, while each combination is presented in two versions: with and without liming. The plots are not replicated. I've got 16S high-througput sequencing outputs that are taxonomic compositional data of soil prokaryotic communities. I basically wanted to make a model of some kind to test the significance of factors and their interference. I've been thinking about a generalized linear model with Poisson distribution, but I'm not sure whether there is a valid way to analyze my data since there are no replicates present in the experiments.

Edit. Adding the experiment design table.
[image: experiment design]

Comment: That's 11 rows. The lack of replicates is problematic as there's no way to tell apart extra-Poisson variation between plots & differences between cell means from a saturated model. It's not a matter of valid/invalid but of how happy you are having to rely on assumptions you can't check. Also, how are the plots laid out physically?

Comment: @Scortchi there is some buffer space between them to eliminate intermixing. The sad part is that the field is partly heterogeneous in terms of the soil type, thus some samples occupy a minor soil medium.

Comment: Is the assignment of plants/treatments to plots randomized?

Comment: @Scortchi the table above precisely represents the design.

Comment: The physical lay-out of the plots also?!

Comment: @Scortchi yep. The experiment is more than one hundred years old. Back then no one thought about metagenomics and valid modeling.

Comment: That introduces another difficulty into interpretation of the results - at least the controls aren't next to each other.

Comment: I've just noticed there are 2 controls - so you do have *some* replicates to assess over-dispersion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much difference from analysing an unreplicated Gaussian model; though under the Poisson model the variance is equal to the mean, there's no way to unconfound extra-Poisson variability arising from heterogeneity among plots from higher order interactions. In this case, however, there are *two* control treatments which presumably can be considered replicates; so even a saturated model would be left with twelve residual degrees of freedom. 'Manure' is the only factor not crossed with all the others

More problematic is the lack of randomization noted in your comments— there may be confounding variables gradated across the field.